# How to force uninstall a module from pip3

Tags: python-3.x, pip

Not sure how this happen, I downloaded a module from source and install it as per the steps...

When I run this command, I am getting this weird name of the module

```
pip3 freeze | grep luma
    
-e git+https://github.com/rm-hull/max7219.git@5ee313bd4c72c9297129094239baeba7766092f0#egg=luma.led_matrix
```

I wanted to uninstall it but, when I run this code..I am getting this.

```
pip3 uninstall "-e git+https://github.com/rm-hull/max7219.git@5ee313bd4c72c9297129094239baeba7766092f0#egg=luma.led_matrix"

Usage:
  pip3 uninstall [options] <package> ...
  pip3 uninstall [options] -r <requirements file> ...

no such option: -e
```

How can I remove that module in my python3 path library?

**Update:**
I tried running

```
pip3 show "-e git+https://github.com/rm-hull/max7219.git@5ee313bd4c72c9297129094239baeba7766092f0#egg=luma.led_matrix"

Usage:
  pip3 show [options] <package> ...

no such option: -e
```

Not sure how do I remove this?

Comment: try to remove the `-e`, just: `pip3 uninstall "git+https://github.com/rm-hull/max7219.git@5ee313bd4c72c9297129094239baeba7766092f0#egg=luma.led_matrix"
`

Comment: Remove the `egg` file - `rm -r $(find . -name '*.egg-info')` then do `pip3 uninstall <package_name?`

Comment: tried removing the -e but it doesn't work as well

Comment: where should I find the egg file?

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal window.
To uninstall, or remove, a package use the command '$PIP uninstall '. This example will remove the flask package. ...
The command will ask for confirmation after listing the files to be removed.

Answer (score -1):

Can u try by removing quotes

Eg:
pip3 uninstall git+https://github.com/rmhull/max7219.git@5ee313bd4c72c9297129094239baeba7766092f0#egg=luma.led_matrix

Comment: Can't uninstall 'luma.led-matrix'. No files were found to uninstall.